# SQL i want display only the same

Tags: sql, database

```
Name table university its PRIMARY KEY

U_Address is location of university
```

I want Display the university name that is located at the same address

Create table university(
U_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
U_Name varchar (50) NOT NULL,
U_Address varchar (50),
U_Type varchar(50) DEFAULT 'Public University'
);

```
select U_Address 
from university  
where U_Address = U_Address;

insert into university values (10, 'EE','RU', 'Public university');
insert into university values (20, 'EX','CH', 'Private university');
insert into university values (30, 'AK','CH', 'Public university');
```

Comment: Same address as what?

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample

Comment: Display the name of any university in the same city name is U_name

Comment: (I only want to view which universities are in (CH

Answer (score 0):

Straight ahead would be a subselect

```
SELECT * from university u1 
 where exists ( select U_Name from university u2 where u1.U_ID <> u2.U_ID
                     and u1.U_Address = u2.U_Address)
```

Another way: Find the adresses with more then one university and join this with the universities

```
SELECT u1.* from university u1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT U_Address from university 
                 GORUP BY U_Address
                 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) u2
    ON u1.U_Address = u2.U_Address
```